# How to run a url without opening the page? -Angular

Tags: angular

I have a url that when run can executes a function that changes a database. I need to run it from an Angular website without opening to make it look nice to users. Currently the way I have done it opens the page was activated, is there any way to run the url without opening the page?

**HTML**

```
 <div class="add" (click)="onNavigateadd()">
   <img width="80%" src="assets/img/add.png" >
 </div>
```

**Typescript**

```
  onNavigateadd(){
    window.open('http://www.example.com')
  }
```

Comment: Are you trying to refer to an `API`?

Comment: So you just want to do an HTTP request?

Comment: You can invoke that method in the `ngOnInit()` of *that* component.

Comment: As Ramesh say, you simple inject httpClient and make a this.httpClient.get(...) -or this.httpClient.post(...), see https://angular.io/guide/http

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If you only want to run it then you can run in a new tab so this URL will open in a new tab, for that you can use href like this
In HTML:**

```
<a href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank">google.com</a>
```